# Retrieving messages supported by entity type

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-crm-sdk

For each of the [CRUD request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) there's a table with supported entities. Is there any way to obtain such info from SDK/WebAPI per entity type?

Probably some metadata properties or separate requests to check?

Comment: I think the goal is 1:1 parity between services, although I'm not sure if it is there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/event-framework#available-events) should help you.

> To verify if a message and entity combination supports execution of plug-ins using a database query, you can use the following Web API query:

```
{{webapiurl}}sdkmessages?$select=name
&$filter=isprivate eq false 
and (name ne 'SetStateDynamicEntity' 
and name ne 'RemoveRelated' 
and name ne 'SetRelated' and 
name ne 'Execute') 
and sdkmessageid_sdkmessagefilter/any(s:s/iscustomprocessingstepallowed eq true 
and s/isvisible eq true)
&$expand=sdkmessageid_sdkmessagefilter($select=primaryobjecttypecode;
$filter=iscustomprocessingstepallowed eq true and isvisible eq true)
&$orderby=name
```

Fetchxml version:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name='sdkmessage' >
    <attribute name='name' />
    <link-entity name='sdkmessagefilter' alias='filter' to='sdkmessageid' from='sdkmessageid' link-type='inner' >
      <filter type='and' >
        <condition attribute='iscustomprocessingstepallowed' operator='eq' value='1' />
        <condition attribute='isvisible' operator='eq' value='1' />
      </filter>
      <attribute name='primaryobjecttypecode' />
    </link-entity>
    <filter>
      <condition attribute='isprivate' operator='eq' value='0' />
      <condition attribute='name' operator='not-in' >
        <value>SetStateDynamicEntity</value>
        <value>RemoveRelated</value>
        <value>SetRelated</value>
          <value>Execute</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
    <order attribute='name' />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```